# How can I create a BigQuery record with a join, but without specifying all fields?

Tags: sql, join, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Question: How to join tables using join clause without listing all the fields?

### Data

Given two tables, Person and Address:

**Person**

| name | address_id |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 10 |
| Bob | 11 |
| Charlie | 10 |

**Address**

| id | street | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | William Street | NYC |
| 11 | Old Street | London |

### Desired result:

I'd like to join them with a record, like so:

| name | address.street | address.city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | William Street | NYC |
| Bob | Old Street | London |
| Charlie | William Street | NYC |

However, I have many columns in both tables and I don't want to specify them all.

So something a bit like using `EXCEPT` but with the joined columns becoming nested in an `address` record:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (address_id)
FROM person p
JOIN address a
ON p.address_id = a.id
```

Is this possible in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below query:

```sql
SELECT p.* EXCEPT(address_id), (SELECT AS STRUCT a.* EXCEPT(id)) AS address
  FROM Person p JOIN Address a ON p.address_id = a.id;
```

output:

[image]

You can join more tables with similar approach.

```sql
SELECT p.* EXCEPT(address_id), 
       (SELECT AS STRUCT a.* EXCEPT(id)) AS address,
       (SELECT AS STRUCT j.* EXCEPT(name)) AS Job
  FROM Person p
  JOIN Address a ON p.address_id = a.id
  JOIN Job j ON p.name = j.name;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, one clarification perhaps - I actually have more than two tables, and it looks like the third joined table has its columns added both inside and outside a struct. So if I have `Person`, `Address` and `Job` with fields `Title` and `Salary`, I end up with these columns: `name, address.street, address.city, title, salary, job.title, job.salary`. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @Yaniv Aknin,  I've updated my answer to join more tables.  kindly check that out.

Comment: Hmm, no, that doesn't seem sufficient. The intention is *not* to have to repeat the field names. But a query like [this](https://pastebin.com/1tpGpUQC) returns the columns **both** in a record and in the toplevel column space ([example](https://imgur.com/NlCIoSw)). Can they be excluded without listing them one by one?

Comment: Unfortuntely, if you use **SELECT \* EXCEPT ( address_id )** instead of **SELECT p.\* EXCEPT ( address_id )**, there is no way to do that as I know.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, I added that mistake preparing the simplified example - you are right that `p.*` fixes it. In my real query I used `p.*`, but *still* have fields spilling over. My real query has a lot more columns, some of them nested. I'll try to prepare a better example and comment here later on, thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: OK, final update - I've tried to reproduce with a [simpler query](https://pastebin.com/3yuqthcX) and it worked fine. So I deleted the view I was using and recreated it, rewriting the query - and it worked OK this time. I can only imagine I made a mistake somewhere and couldn't find it. Thank you again, I found `SELECT AS STRUCT x.* EXCEPT` very useful.

Comment: @Yaniv , I've answered it in the question you've posted. Kindly check that out if it is what you want.