# How to add/remove struct fields without re-specifying all other fields in BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the following data shape and working BigQuery query:

```sql
WITH
Person AS (
  SELECT 'Alice' AS name, 10 AS address_id,
         [STRUCT("Rexi" AS name, 5 AS species_id), STRUCT("Luna", 6)] AS pets UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 11, [STRUCT("Ralfie", 5)] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Chandra', 10, []),
Address AS (
  SELECT 10 AS id, 'Jump Street' AS street, 'UK' AS country UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 'Paper Street', 'US'
  ),
Species AS (
  SELECT 5 AS id, 'Dog' as name, 11 as lifespan UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'Cat', 15
)
SELECT p.* EXCEPT (address_id),
  (SELECT AS STRUCT a.* EXCEPT(id)) AS address
FROM Person p
  JOIN Address a ON p.address_id = a.id
```

As we can see, `Person` has a `pets` array of records, and a joinable id with `address`. Each pet also has a joinable id with `species`.

Just like I've used `SELECT p.* EXCEPT (address_id)` to remove the `address_id` from my result and join address as a struct on each person, I wish I could remove the `species_id` field and join species as a struct on each pet.

i.e., I wish I had syntax like `SELECT p.* EXCEPT (address_id, pets[*].species_id)` and an ability to "join inside the struct".

My ideal result would be a query that doesn't have to repeat all species field names, but has results like this:

```json
[{
  "name": "Alice",
  "pets": [{
    "name": "Rexi",
    "species": {
      "name": "Dog",
      "lifespan": 11,
    }
  }, {
    "name": "Luna",
    "species": {
      "name": "Cat",
      "lifespan": 15,
    }
  }],
  "address": {
    "street": "Jump Street",
    "country": "UK"
  }
},
<...>]
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: you can use json functions https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions?hl=de or normalize your datastructure get rid of json and use "noraml sql"

Comment: Hmm... seems like you know a lot more about SQL than I do, but I'm not sure I agree with the paradigm you suggest in the case of something like BigQuery or Snowflake. I thought a datalake strategy makes it reasonable to ELT rather than ETL, and I'm trying to figure out how to transform the data I already have given a structure I may not easily be able to "get rid of". Why is this not a valid question?

Comment: if you want json as datapy and nee to extract all or most data see https://www.holistics.io/blog/how-to-extract-nested-or-array-json-in-bigquery/  but json needs at all  times a quite high level of learning, but see the tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a followup answer of [How can I create a BigQuery record with a join, but without specifying all fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72723272/how-can-i-create-a-bigquery-record-with-a-join-but-without-specifying-all-field), consider below query:

```sql
SELECT p.* EXCEPT (address_id) REPLACE (
         ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT p.* EXCEPT(species_id),
               (SELECT AS STRUCT s.* EXCEPT(id)) AS species
                  FROM UNNEST(pets) p JOIN Species s ON p.species_id = s.id
              )
         AS pets 
       ),
       (SELECT AS STRUCT a.* EXCEPT(id)) AS address
  FROM Person p
  JOIN Address a ON p.address_id = a.id;
```

output will be:

[image]

Comment: Really not as hard as I feared; I thought we'd have to reconstruct `pets` in a `WITH` subquery. Thanks again, @Jaytiger!

Comment: Yes, same approach, only difference is it's applied to **select** clause  in an inner subquery.

Comment: The new thing for me was the use of `REPLACE`; I missed this keyword when scanning through the docs.